# Though I have changed the language of my visual studio installer to Korean but uninstaller shows in English in the start up of uninstallation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, uninstallation

I have created an installer using Visual Studio 2010. And I have set the language to korean. Installer works fine and all the messages are shown in Korean. But the problem is in uninstaller. I have created uninstaller and the uninstaller executable executes the following command

```
WinExec("msiexec.exe /x {1F13D24F-9D04-440E-AC1C-8CCCE55E79AB}", SW_SHOW);
```

When I try to uninstall all works fine except in the start up there shows a message in english. The picture is given below -

[image]

How can I change the language of the above picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I am giving the answer to my own question so that if anyone faces the same issue then it can be helpful for him.

Solution:

- Go to **View->Editor->User Interfaces**.
- Remove the **Welcome** dialog.
- Again add the **Welcome** dialog.
- Build msi, and your issue will be solved.

There may be other solutions, but this solution worked for me.